# R Combinar 2 tablas dejando solo el nombre de las columnas en comun

Tags: r, rstudio

¿como puedo combinar 2 tablas y que el resultado sea otra tabla solo con las columnas en comun?

```
tabla_a <-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,25,replace = TRUE), ncol=5))
tabla_b <-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,25,replace = TRUE), ncol=3))
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es el criterio para relacionar ambas tablas?

Comment: el nombre de la columna

Comment: Solo quiero que me deje las columnas que existen en las 2 tablas

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es la unión de las dos tablas y conservar solo las columnas en común:

```
cols <- colnames(tabla_a) %in% colnames(tabla_b)
rbind(tabla_a[, cols], tabla_b[, cols])
```

Simplemente ubicamos las columnas que comparten y con `rbind` unimos ambos `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

una solución empelando la librería dplyr seria:

primero identifica el df que tiene mas columnas, asumamos que tabla_a tiene mas columnas que tabla_b ...

podrías primero quedarte solo con las columnas de la tabla_a en comun con tabla_b y posteriormente unirlas

```
 tabla_a1 <- tabla_a[, intersect(names(tabla_a), names(tabla_b))]
 tabla_ab <- rbind(tabla_a1, tabla_b)
```

o hacerlo en una sola linea, depende como lo prefieras

```
tabla_ab <- rbind(tabla_a[, intersect(names(tabla_a), names(tabla_b))], tabla_b)
```